# Constraining type variables in locales

Tags: isabelle

The Isabelle library contains the classes `real_inner` and `real_normed_vector`, the latter of which is declared a subclass of the former in `~~src/HOL/Library/Inner_Product.thy`.

Now, suppose we have a locale

```
locale foo =
  fixes goo :: "'a::{real_normed_vector} => bool"
```

and wish to extend this locale with some new constants, and also constraining the sort of `'a` to be `real_inner` at the same time, like so:

```
locale extended = foo +
  fixes ext :: "'a::{real_inner} => nat"
```

Is there a way to do this?  Trying to do this using the examples above sees Isabelle give goo the type `'b::{real_normed_vector} => bool` in `extended`, when I instead require the type `'a::{real_inner} => bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
locale extended = foo goo
  for goo :: "'a :: real_inner ⇒ bool" +
  fixes ext :: "'a => nat"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this before asking the question but another problem disguised what was going wrong.  Fixed and working now.